# Windows Phone 8.0 SEHException at Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundTransfer.BtsApi.BtsNotificationCallback.OnNotify(Int32 hrNotify, IntPtr notifyData)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am facing with an issue wherein during image uploads(600+) using BackgroundTransferService, the following exception occurs under the app's UnhandledException section

```
ExceptionObject = {System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: External component has thrown an exception.at Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundTransfer.BtsApi.BtsNotificationCallback.OnNotify(Int32 hrNotify, IntPtr notifyData)}
```

I have put try catch blocks in all the places where am using BackgroundTransferService but no exception is getting caught.

This exception occurs only after few hundred images have been uploaded.

I am using VS 2012/2013

Can anyone please help me in pointing me to the right direction?

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve? Is your workflow logic for BackgroundTransfer conforms BackgroundTransferServer requirements?

Comment: @Uday0119 Am currently using rest api to upload images from the device to a server,which the rest api is taking care of.Below is an example of the same.

BackgroundTransferRequest btr = new BackgroundTransferRequest(new Uri(serviceUploadLocationURL, UriKind.Absolute));
btr.Method = "POST";
btr.Headers.Add("uid", (Constants.strUserName.ToString()));
btr.Headers.Add("pwd",(Uri.EscapeDataString(Constants.strPassword.ToString())));    
Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundTransfer.BackgroundTransferService.Add(btr);

Comment: Are you uploading images one-by-one or all of them in a single request?

Comment: I am uploading one by one in a for loop

Comment: check in you app, if anything is exploited or not conformed to Background Transfer policies as defined in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202955.aspx. There is possibility that your uploads are queued and it throw exception when queue exceed 500

Comment: I am uploading as per the policies mentioned in the link i.e. am not exceeding the upload queue. Additionally am little confused as to the exception which I am getting.Because the exception seems to be occurring at BtsNotificationCallback which I believe is to trigger the event delegate , TransferStatusChanged or TransferProgressChanged.If that is the case then am clearly not exploiting any Background Transfer policies. Additionally I would like to ask if there are any specific exception list which will tell me if any of the policies expectations are not met.

Comment: Hi have got any solution to this problem ? i am getting the similar exception